# Parallax background image for top-bottom and not right-left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I wrote a script that changes the BG position as you scroll down, its works good for left and right positions but i cant seem to reach the syntax that will allow me to parallax the background-position top or bottom - instead of right and left.

here is my code:

```
function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('section.intro .custombg').css('background-position',(scrolled * -0.2) + 'px');}
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        parallax();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The css attribute `background-position` has two values, #horizontal #vertical.
See: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position

Consider something like:

```
function parallax(){
    var scrolledTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrolledLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
    $('section.intro .custombg').css('background-position',(scrolledLeft * -0.2) + 'px ' + (scrolledTop * -0.2) + 'px');}
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        parallax();
    });
}
```

Also, this seems like it will add the scroll event every time the parallax method is called.  To correct this, you could try:

```
function parallax(top, left) {
    $('section.intro .custombg').css('background-position',(left * -0.2) + 'px ' + (top * -0.2) + 'px');}
} // end function

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        parallax($(window).scrollTop(), $(window).scrollLeft()); // call the method
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('section.intro .custombg').css('background-position','center ' + (scrolled * -0.2) + 'px');}
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        parallax();
    });
}
```

Comment: You're exponentially attaching a gazillion scroll listeners there.

Answer (score 0):

This is all wrong, you are setting up an event handler each time you use $(window).scroll(). You only need to do that once. Try this.

```
var scrolledTop,
    scrolledLeft,
    background_position,
    $custom_bg;


function parallax(){
    scrolledTop = window.scrollY,
    scrolledLeft = window.scrollX,
    background_position = (scrolledLeft * -0.2) + 'px ' + (scrolledTop * -0.2) + 'px');

    console.log('background_position', background_position);
    $custom_bg.css('background-position', background_position);
}

$(function() {

    $custom_bg = $('section.intro .custombg');


    $(window).on('scroll', parallax);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do more with parallax and change other properties as, I'd highly recommend the Skrollr library (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

You can vary almost any CSS property as you scroll, giving you more options than just background position or something else. It might be more than you're looking for, but it's pretty lightweight and has mobile support, too (which you could have trouble accounting for without a well-developed library). Hope it helps!

For example, if you wanted to shift the background-position of a background image, you could simply do the following: 
initialize skrollr (in this case without options, but there are parameters you can set)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var s = skrollr.init();
    </script>
```

Then, you're able to use simple data-tags to tell Skrollr which elements you want to make fancy and which you don't. In your case, you could do something vaguely like the following:

(whatever element you want to use parallax on)

```
<div data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);transform[bounce]:rotate(0deg);" data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);transform[bounce]:rotate(360deg);">
    WOOOT
</div>
```

However, you'd swap background-color out for background-position

```
<div data-0="background-position: 0px 0px" data-700="background-position: 0px 100px">       </div>
```

or

```
<div data-0="background-position: top center" data-700="background-position: bottom center">       </div>
```

You can use any of the accepted CSS `background-position` keywords.

**Useful:** 
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Edited to reflect. Sorted.